# How to add rectangle area selection to a pan-/zoomable VB.Net Winforms control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, zooming, panel, pan

this is my first question after finding this site.

I'm currently trying to create a VB.NET user control that contains a panel on which some
graphics objects (circles, rectangles, lines) should be drawn during the Paint event.
It may simplify the case that the panel always will be square (width = height).
Using a picturebox for drawing is unfortunately not an option for me. I also don't want
to use autoscroll and have visible scrollbars.

The panel should be pan-/zoomable by the user. Panning should be done by pressing the
middle mouse button and zooming should be done by scrolling the mouse wheel. 
I already found good examples how to implement these functionalities and so far they work
very well.
Now I also want to add the feature that the user should be able to zoom to a specific
(square) area of the panel by a selection rectangle that is displayed when he presses
the left mouse button and it's size adjusts while he is moving the mouse with pressed 
left button. (It should be a similar behavior like e. g. zooming into a PDF document). 
This is were I got stuck.

I extracted the part of the code that is responsible for the panel and it's events and
this is what I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private zoomstart as Point
    Private zoomfirst as Point
    Private zoomwidth as Integer    
    Private zoomrect as Rectangle
    Private WithEvents tmrMarch as New Timer
    Private MarchOffset as Integer = 0
    Private OffsetDelta as Integer = 2
    Private DashPattern() as Single = {5, 5}

    Private zoom As Single = 1.0
    Private startx as Integer = 0
    Private starty as Integer = 0
    Private offsetx as Integer = 0
    Private offsety as Integer = 0
    Private mouseDownPt as Point
    Private initialwidth As Integer

    Public WithEvents Canvas1 As New Canvas

    Private Enum T_MouseAction
        RectangleZooming
        WheelZooming
        Panning
        None
    End Enum

    Private MouseAction As T_MouseAction = T_MouseAction.None


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Canvas1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Width)
        Canvas1.AutoScroll = False
        initialwidth = Canvas1.Width
        Me.Controls.Add(Canvas1)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Canvas1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.Paint
        Select Case MouseAction
            Case T_MouseAction.None
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetx, offsety)
                e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom)
            Case T_MouseAction.Panning
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetx, offsety)
                e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom)
            Case T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetx, offsety)
                e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom)
            Case T_MouseAction.WheelZooming
                e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetx, offsety)
        End Select
        Call DrawImage(e.Graphics)
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming Then
            MarchOffset = MarchOffset + OffsetDelta
            Dim pen as New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
            pen.DashPattern = DashPattern
            pen.DashOffset = MarchOffset
            pen.Color = Color.Red
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, zoomrect)
        End If 
    End Sub


    Private Sub DrawImage(ByVal gr As Graphics)
        Dim rect As Rectangle
        rect = New Rectangle(0, 0, initialwidth, initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.375 * initialwidth, 0.375 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.375 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightBlue, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.625 * initialwidth, 0.625 * initialwidth)
        gr.DrawArc(Pens.Red, rect, 20, 140)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.25 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.625 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.6875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rect)
    End Sub



    Private Sub tmrMarch_Tick(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles tmrMarch.Tick
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    




    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then
            MouseAction = T_MouseAction.Panning
            mouseDownPt = e.Location
            startx = offsetx
            starty = offsety
        End If
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            zoomstart = e.Location
            tmrMarch.Interval = 100
            tmrMarch.Enabled = True
        End If        
    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseUp
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        tmrMarch.Enabled = False
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming Then
            Dim oldzoom as Single = zoom

            zoom = 1 ' <=== ?

            zoom = Math.Truncate(zoom / 0.2) * 0.2

            Dim oldoffsetx, oldoffsety as Integer
            Dim newoffsetx, newoffsety as Integer
            oldoffsetx = CInt(zoomrect.X / oldzoom)
            oldoffsety = CInt(zoomrect.Y / oldzoom)
            newoffsetx = CInt(zoomrect.X / zoom)
            newoffsety = CInt(zoomrect.Y / zoom)

            offsetx = newoffsetx - oldoffsetx + offsetx ' <=== ?
            offsety = newoffsety - oldoffsety + offsety ' <=== ?    
        End If
        MouseAction = T_MouseAction.None
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            Dim mousePosNow as Point = e.Location
            Dim deltaX, deltaY as Integer
            deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDownPt.X
            deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDownPt.Y
            offsetx = CInt(startx + deltaX)
            offsety = CInt(starty + deltaY)
            MouseAction = T_MouseAction.Panning
            Canvas1.Refresh
        End If

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim loc as Point
            loc = e.Location
            Dim sizex, sizey as Integer
            sizex = Math.Abs(zoomstart.X - loc.X)
            sizey = Math.Abs(zoomstart.Y - loc.Y)
            zoomwidth = Math.Max(sizex, sizey)
            If loc.X < zoomstart.X Then
                zoomfirst.X = loc.X
            Else
                zoomfirst.X = zoomstart.x
            End If
            If loc.Y < zoomstart.Y Then
                zoomfirst.Y = loc.Y
            Else
                zoomfirst.Y = zoomstart.Y
            End If
            If zoomwidth > 10 Then
                MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming
            End If
            zoomrect = New Rectangle(zoomfirst, New Size(zoomwidth, zoomwidth))
            Canvas1.Refresh
        End If        
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseWheel
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.Panning Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim oldzoom as Single = zoom
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            zoom = zoom + 0.2
        End If
        If e.Delta < 0 Then
            zoom = Math.Max(zoom - 0.2, 0.2)
        End If
        Dim mousePosNow as Point = e.Location
        Dim x, y as Integer
        x = mousePosNow.X
        y = mousePosNow.Y
        Dim oldoffsetx, oldoffsety as Integer
        Dim newoffsetx, newoffsety as Integer
        oldoffsetx = CInt(x / oldzoom)
        oldoffsety = CInt(y / oldzoom)
        newoffsetx = CInt(x / zoom)
        newoffsety = CInt(y / zoom)
        offsetx = newoffsetx - oldoffsetx + offsetx
        offsety = newoffsety - oldoffsety + offsety
        MouseAction = T_MouseAction.WheelZooming
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseEnter
        Canvas1.Focus
    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseLeave
        Me.Focus
    End Sub    

End Class


Public Class Canvas
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Credits go to Rod Stephens for the code of the smiley face that in this case is just a placeholder 
for the graphics later to be drawn in the user control.
(http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/scale-a-drawing-so-it-fits-a-target-area-in-c/)

The zoom rectangle (marching ants) is already properly created in the MouseMove event.
In the MouseUp event I want to apply the zoom and scale the selected area to the size
of the panel. In the Paint event the actual zooming is handled by ScaleTransform and 
TranslateTransform operations.

But I can't figure out how to calculate the appropriate zoom factor and x/y offsets so the
selected area scales to the panel size. I tried to orientate at the code that is used for
the mouse wheel zooming. I'm a little bit confused since it looks to me that there are
actually two zoom factors involved: one that is influenced by the mouse wheel operation
and one that is linked to the selection rectangle operation.
I also tried to calculate the zoom factor as something like "selection.width/panel.width",
but that only brings "jumpy" behavior to the panel navigation and doesn't scale properly.

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by myself.
Only one order of transformations is needed in the Paint event.
The zoom-to-rectangle stuff is handled in the MouseUp event.
The zoomed area doesn't 100% fit the borders of the zoom selection
rectangle, but the achieved solution is good enough for my needs.

Here is the working solution:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private zoomstart as Point
    Private zoomfirst as Point
    Private zoomwidth as Integer    
    Private zoomrect as Rectangle
    Private maxzoom As Decimal = 5
    Private minzoom As Decimal = 0.2
    Private WithEvents tmrMarch as New Timer
    Private MarchOffset as Integer = 0
    Private OffsetDelta as Integer = 2
    Private DashPattern() as Single = {5, 5}

    Private zoom As Decimal = 1
    Private startx as Integer = 0
    Private starty as Integer = 0
    Private offsetx as Integer
    Private offsety as Integer
    Private mouseDownPt as Point
    Private initialwidth As Integer

    Public WithEvents Canvas1 As New Canvas

    Private Enum T_MouseAction
        RectangleZooming
        Panning
        None
    End Enum

    Private MouseAction As T_MouseAction = T_MouseAction.None


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Canvas1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Width)
        Canvas1.AutoScroll = False
        initialwidth = Canvas1.Width
        Me.Controls.Add(Canvas1)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Canvas1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.Paint
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(CSng(zoom), CSng(zoom))
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(offsetx, offsety)        
        Call DrawImage(e.Graphics)
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming Then
            MarchOffset = MarchOffset + OffsetDelta
            Dim pen as New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
            pen.DashPattern = DashPattern
            pen.DashOffset = MarchOffset
            pen.Color = Color.Red
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, zoomrect)
        End If 
    End Sub


    Private Sub DrawImage(ByVal gr As Graphics)
        Dim rect As Rectangle
        rect = New Rectangle(0, 0, initialwidth, initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.375 * initialwidth, 0.375 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.375 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightBlue, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.625 * initialwidth, 0.625 * initialwidth)
        gr.DrawArc(Pens.Red, rect, 20, 140)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.25 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.625 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.1875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect)
        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect)
        rect = New Rectangle(0.6875 * initialwidth, 0.25 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth, 0.125 * initialwidth)
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rect)
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrMarch_Tick(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles tmrMarch.Tick
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle Then
            MouseAction = T_MouseAction.Panning
            mouseDownPt = e.Location
            startx = offsetx
            starty = offsety
        End If
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            zoomstart = e.Location
            tmrMarch.Interval = 100
            tmrMarch.Enabled = True
        End If        
    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseUp
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        tmrMarch.Enabled = False
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming Then
            Dim oldzoom as Decimal = zoom
            zoom = Canvas1.Width / zoomrect.Width * zoom
            zoom = Math.Round(zoom / 0.2) * 0.2
            zoom = Math.Max(zoom, minzoom)
            zoom = Math.Min(zoom, maxzoom)
            Dim oldoffsetx, oldoffsety as Integer
            Dim newoffsetx, newoffsety as Integer
            oldoffsetx = CInt((zoomrect.X + zoomrect.Width / 2) / oldzoom)
            oldoffsety = CInt((zoomrect.Y + zoomrect.Height / 2) / oldzoom)
            newoffsetx = CInt((zoomrect.X + zoomrect.Width / 2) / zoom)
            newoffsety = CInt((zoomrect.Y + zoomrect.Height / 2) / zoom)
            offsetx = newoffsetx - oldoffsetx + offsetx
            offsety = newoffsety - oldoffsety + offsety
        End If
        MouseAction = T_MouseAction.None
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            Dim mousePosNow as Point = e.Location
            Dim deltaX, deltaY as Integer
            deltaX = CInt((mousePosNow.X - mouseDownPt.X) / zoom)
            deltaY = CInt((mousePosNow.Y - mouseDownPt.Y) / zoom)
            offsetx = CInt(startx + deltaX)
            offsety = CInt(starty + deltaY)
            Canvas1.Refresh
        End If

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim loc as Point
            loc = e.Location
            Dim sizex, sizey as Integer
            sizex = Math.Abs(zoomstart.X - loc.X)
            sizey = Math.Abs(zoomstart.Y - loc.Y)
            zoomwidth = Math.Max(sizex, sizey)
            If loc.X < zoomstart.X Then
                zoomfirst.X = loc.X
            Else
                zoomfirst.X = zoomstart.x
            End If
            If loc.Y < zoomstart.Y Then
                zoomfirst.Y = loc.Y
            Else
                zoomfirst.Y = zoomstart.Y
            End If
            If zoomwidth > 10 Then
                MouseAction = T_MouseAction.RectangleZooming
            End If
            zoomrect = New Rectangle(zoomfirst, New Size(zoomwidth, zoomwidth))
            Canvas1.Refresh
        End If        
    End Sub    


    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as MouseEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseWheel
        If MouseAction = T_MouseAction.Panning Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim oldzoom as Decimal = zoom
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            zoom = Math.Min(zoom + 0.2, maxzoom)
        End If
        If e.Delta < 0 Then
            zoom = Math.Max(zoom - 0.2, minzoom)
        End If
        Dim mousePosNow as Point = e.Location
        Dim x, y as Integer
        x = mousePosNow.X
        y = mousePosNow.Y
        Dim oldoffsetx, oldoffsety as Integer
        Dim newoffsetx, newoffsety as Integer
        oldoffsetx = CInt(x / oldzoom)
        oldoffsety = CInt(y / oldzoom)
        newoffsetx = CInt(x / zoom)
        newoffsety = CInt(y / zoom)
        offsetx = newoffsetx - oldoffsetx + offsetx
        offsety = newoffsety - oldoffsety + offsety
        Canvas1.Refresh
    End Sub    

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseEnter
        Canvas1.Focus
    End Sub

    Private Sub Canvas1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseLeave
        Me.Focus
    End Sub    

End Class


Public Class Canvas
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```